# okhttp: non-static method redirectsToGet(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, mockwebserver

Updated androidTestImplementation from

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.0'
```

to

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.0.1'
```

and started getting: non-static method redirectsToGet(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: If you changed nothing more, you should question the developers of the library, not a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 4):

It's in `okhttp3.internal.http.HttpMethod` and

> [The okhttp3.internal package is not a published API and we change it frequently without warning. Depending on code in this package is bad and will cause you problems with any upgrade! But the 4.x will be particularly painful to naughty developers that import from this package! We changed a lot to take advantage of sweet Kotlin features.](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/)